# Cannot access Centos sshd on Docker

Tags: centos, docker

I read an article that [SSH Daemon Service](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/running_ssh_service/). 
But I want to run on Centos6.4. So I setup from official centos image with almost same istruction.
Then I connect to centos sshd server, but connection is closed immediately.
Here is the message.

```
ssh root@localhost -p 49164
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:49164 ([127.0.0.1]:49164)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 88:71:89:e5:30:91:78:5c:bf:cb:88:c2:5b:81:1a:b5.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:49164' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@localhost's password: 
Connection to localhost closed.
```

Why I cannot connect centos sshd server?

Answer (score 20):

Had the same issue here, works fine if you turn off PAM in the sshd config.

Here are the relevant lines from our Dockerfile

```
RUN sed -ri 's/UsePAM yes/#UsePAM yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -ri 's/#UsePAM no/UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: Is it really such a good idea to just turn PAM off? I'm not very familiar with ssh, but PAM stands for "Pluggable Authentication Module", which sounds kinda useful.

Comment: I had a similar issue with PAM and it turn out to be this http://gaijin-nippon.blogspot.se/2013/07/audit-on-lxc-host.html `pam_loginuid.so` seems to be broken for containers somehow.

Answer (score 4):

I have sshd working with the "centos" image from Docker repo:

- I did *not* need to modify sshd_config i.e. the default `UsePAM yes` is set
- I did need to run `/etc/init.d/sshd start` in my Dockerfile as that generates keys on the first run.
- I did need to fix permissions on `.ssh`

My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y openssh-server sudo

RUN  /etc/init.d/sshd start

RUN useradd admin -G wheel
RUN echo 'admin:secret' | chpasswd
RUN echo '%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

RUN mkdir -p /home/admin/.ssh
ADD authorized_keys /home/admin/.ssh/
RUN chown -R admin:admin /home/admin/.ssh; chmod 700 /home/admin/.ssh

EXPOSE 22
CMD    ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Comment: What is authorized_keys?

Comment: Which version of centos image it works? I am getting /bin/sh: /etc/init.d/sshd: No such file or directory on centos:7 and centos:8

Comment: @JJRoman it would have been Centos6 (sorry, I should have specified that). Centos7+ moved away from initv scripts to systemd

Answer (score 2):

I also had to generate server keys, before that "ssh -v" would just immediately exit with

```
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT
Connection closed by ...
```

Here's my working (Vagrant 1.3.5 and docker 0.7) Dockerfile configuration for sshd:

```
# sshd
RUN echo 'root:secret' | chpasswd
RUN yum install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd ; chmod -rx /var/run/sshd
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419412/ssh-connection-stop-at-debug1-ssh2-msg-kexinit-sent
RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
# Bad security, add a user and sudo instead!
RUN sed -ri 's/#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173889/cannot-access-centos-sshd-on-docker
RUN sed -ri 's/UsePAM yes/#UsePAM yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -ri 's/#UsePAM no/UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

####################
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
EXPOSE 10389 22
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

My supervisord.conf:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
autorestart=true
```

Comment: What's the root password for login?

Comment: Sorry, I had left out the chpasswd step to set the root user's password.

Answer (score 2):

From the Docker website, the example [Dockerizing an SSH Daemon Service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) shows a Dockerfile that addresses this issue.  The important line is the sed command after the comment `SSH login fix`:

```
# sshd
#
# VERSION               0.0.2

FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Sven Dowideit <SvenDowideit@docker.com>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

It's based on an Ubuntu image, but it works for CentOS 6 as well.

Comment: Your link is broken. The new URL is https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

Answer (score 1):

Here is dockerfile that finally worked for me with centos8. Note centos7 & 8 doesn not have systemd enabled by default in official images.

```
FROM centos:8
ENV container docker

#### enabling systemd according to docs on: https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]

### install & configure sshd
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y libcgroup libcgroup-tools openssh-server
### authorize by public key
COPY id_rsa_centos_docker.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chmod a-r /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chmod g-r /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN echo "root:welcome1" | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/UsePAM yes/UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i 's/#PubkeyAuthentication yes/PubkeyAuthentication yes/g'     /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin without-password/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

to run service (even though you dont have local /sys/fs/cgrup like me on macos):

```
docker run -d -p 2022:22 -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/run centos8-sshd "/usr/sbin/init"
```